# Text slightly off center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, flexbox

I'm working on creating a calendar using Bootstrap and React and am running into an issue with the design of the calendar. The text for the top row containing the names of the weekdays are slightly off center with the "day" items in the calendar which will eventually be represented by numbers instead of the word "day".

Playing around with this a bit, I was able to figure out that it is related to the length of the actual text but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve the issue and line up everything perfectly.

Here's the code:

```css
.calendar {
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar--weekdays li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--week li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.calendar--row p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.event__viewer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--  Font Awesome  -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="calendar">
          <h1>My Calendar</h1>
          <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--weekdays">
              <p>Sun</p>
              <p>Mon</p>
              <p>Tue</p>
              <p>Wed</p>
              <p>Thur</p>
              <p>Fri</p>
              <p>Sat</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calendar--tools">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span> Month </span>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 event__viewer">
        <h1>Events</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thoughts on this?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that some of the uppercase characters in the day of the week abbreviations take up more horizontal space, and so their containers will align, but the text itself won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `<p>` here it takes width based on the text inside it, the text is aligned center in their respective `<p>` but since all `<p>` have different width they appear misaligned. This wouldn't be the case if you would have used table.
you can fix a width for all `<p>`.

```css
.calendar {
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar--weekdays li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--week li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.calendar--row p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 30px
}

.event__viewer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--  Font Awesome  -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="calendar">
          <h1>My Calendar</h1>
          <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--weekdays">
              <p>Sun</p>
              <p>Mon</p>
              <p>Tue</p>
              <p>Wed</p>
              <p>Thur</p>
              <p>Fri</p>
              <p>Sat</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calendar--tools">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span> Month </span>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 event__viewer">
        <h1>Events</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm going to rewrite this as a table and see what we can do with that. I'll report back. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Switching up to a table worked perfectly. I did have a weird issue with the styling where the `text-align:center;` didn't work on the `<th>` unless I specifically applied it to the header instead of the table as a whole... nonetheless it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm wondering why you don't use an actual table, if you want to display the info as a table with the markup you already have, you can do that, and it will fix the alignment issue.

Key styles:

```
.calendar {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
.calendar--row {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.calendar--row p {
  display: table-cell;
}
.calendar--tools {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

See it in action:

```css
.calendar {
  text-align: center;
  caption-side: bottom;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.calendar--weekdays li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--week li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.calendar--row {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.calendar--row p {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.event__viewer {
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar--tools {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--  Font Awesome  -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="calendar">
          <h1>My Calendar</h1>
          <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--weekdays">
              <p>Sun</p>
              <p>Mon</p>
              <p>Tue</p>
              <p>Wed</p>
              <p>Thur</p>
              <p>Fri</p>
              <p>Sat</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar--row calendar--week">
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
              <p>day</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="calendar--tools">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span> Month </span>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 event__viewer">
        <h1>Events</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the weekday titles are not lining up with the columns underneath is because they are two separate DOM elements with no relation to each other (other than the box model positioning where the `<div>`s line up under each other).

That is, all the rows are aligning to the center as you have specified. The `<p>` tags that contain your weekday titles have some padding, so **the horizontal width of the characters plus the padding are taken into consideration when centering that row**, which it is centered. You'll notice there is no reference to the week rows under it in that calculation.

One way to relate the rows is to use a `<table>` as others have said. There is some pretty solid advice out there about not using `<table>`s for layout purposes.

Another idea is to set a `min-width` on all the columns. That way the content will align to the center in each "cell" which will have the same width as the cell under it.